# Search and replace variables with special characters in multiple files with perl command in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, perl, replace, grep

Trying to search and replace password variables with special characters in multiple files with a `perl` command in a bash script. So far I have:

```
grep -rlF "${old_pass}" | xargs perl -p -e "s~\Q$old_pass~\E$new_pass~g"
```

and it works for most cases, however sometimes it fails. For example, given `old_pass=*DGB9Twq7WTwz@wR` and `new_pass=tDx6U&ShRv}E3Mdb` the above command results in `tDx6U&ShRv}E3Mdb@wR` instead of just `tDx6U&ShRv}E3Mdb`.

Please note that passwords are generated automatically and can consist of all uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and all special characters. So the working version must be able to take into account (escape) all kind of possible password versions.

Comment: I suspect it's because `@wR` in that example is being treated as an array when it shows up in the regular expression and gets turned into an (empty) string.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using `~` as your regex delimiter, but you are starting your quoting with `\Q` at the beginning of the search regex and ending it with `\E` *after* the delimiter that ends the search and begins the replacement.  Make them both `\Q`, as each ends at the end of the string anyway, and you need to quote the `@` that Perl will try to interpolate as an array sigil.

Comment: you're putting bandaids upon bandaids.... Use `find` to find files and then use `awk` to replace one string with another, it's that simple.

Comment: Ed, I would rather go easier way if there was one found. I tried to explain on another thread to yourself, that CentOS 7.x on which I am working on has GNU Awk 4.0.2, which does not have '-i inplace' option. Only AWK 4.1 and after versions have that feature. So if go with awk then I have to somehow store the output file and then replace the old one, which becomes more complex. Give me working version with awk on the other thread and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You already accepted an answer on your other thread and it DID answer the question you originally posted, now you've accepted an answer on this thread and again it DOES answer the question you posted. You just keep asking how to implement specific parts of the code that you think you need to solve your problem instead of asking how to solve your problem. They've all be [XY Problems](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) so far. Post a complete question and you'll get the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried and failed to generate the correct Perl code. But the real problem is that you tried to generate Perl code form the shell in the first place. There are three primary ways of passing information to Perl without using STDIN or external storage.

- Arguments

  ```
  perl -pe'BEGIN { ($o,$n)=splice(@ARGV,0,2) } s/\Q$o/$n/g' -- "$old_pass" "$new_pass"
  ```
- Command-line options

  In a full program, you'd use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long), but [`perl -s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will do fine here.

  ```
  perl -spe's/\Q$o/$n/g' -- -o="$old_pass" -n="$new_pass" --
  ```
- Environment variables

  ```
  O="$old_pass" N="$new_pass" perl -pe's/\Q$ENV{O}/$ENV{N}/g' --
  ```

  (In your case, you'd have to set the env vars for `xargs` instead of `perl` itself.)

---

By the way, you should further restrict what your regex pattern matches. As it stands, you could have false positives. (Matching the wrong user's password. matching part of a password. Matching something that isn't a password at all.)

Comment: Excellent! All three versions worked for me. Could you please elaborate on the last part of your answer? How exactly I should `further restrict` my regex pattern matches? This was the part of question.

Comment: I was too hasty to accept the answer, because everything worked for me on CLI, however on real bash script it did not. The first one modified with adding `-i` as `grep -rlF "$1" | xargs perl -pi -e'BEGIN { ($o,$n)=splice(@ARGV,0,2) } s/\Q$o/$n/g' -- "$1" "$2"` didn't work. The second one also with `-i` as `grep -rlF "$1" | xargs perl -spi -e's/\Q$o/$n/g' -- --o="$1" --n="$2" --` also failed. I don't know how to try the third one on script.

Comment: Can you please test `grep -rlF "${old_pass}" | xargs perl -spe 's/\Q$o/$n/g' -- --o="$old_pass" --n="$new_pass" --` on your end?

Comment: Should be `-o` and `-n`. That's what I thought, but I copied the double-dash from another answer. Fixed

Comment: All exported environment variables are available inside Perl as key/val pairs in the `%ENV` ("environment") hash. If you set `O=1` on the command line it becomes part of the invocation's env, so inside Perl it would be accessed as `$ENV{O}`.

Comment: @ikegami, you are right - the oneliner `grep -rlF "${old_pass}" | xargs perl -spi -e's/\Q$o/$n/g' -- -o="$old_pass" -n="$new_pass" --` works as expected on command line, but for some reason it is failing to work in a bash script. Do you have any ideas of why it might be failing in a bash script?

Comment: Actually, after fixing my bash script it started to work. Thanks a lot! I do accept your answer.